# How to change Ugly link?

Tags: redirect, urls, links

How to change Ugly link from

> www.test.com/?p=123

to

> test.com/123

I want to make two types of links:

> www.test.com/123-my-post-title-name
>
> www.test.com/123

The latter should lead to the first.

Comment: What is `123`? What is `123-simpenews`?

Comment: its 1 news.

But /123 will redirect to /123-simplenews

You come to test.com/123 and you are redirected to test.com/123-simplenews

Comment: question is still not clear. What do you mean in wanting to have two types of links, when will the one be used and when the other and what process will generate them?

Comment: Now
www.test.com/123-my-post-title-name

www.test.com/?p=123

I want

www.test.com/123-my-post-title-name

www.test.com/123

Answer (score 1):

Settings --> Permalinks. Choose 'post name'.

[See the official Wordpress codex page for more](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Choosing_your_permalink_structure).

Comment: But I need to be redirected from test.com/123 ("123" - post ID) to test.com/123-simplenews ("123"- post ID, "simplenews"- post name)

Answer (score 0):

This Ugly Links you call in *WordPress* is named **Permalinks**. There are many formats of **Permalinks**, such as:

- Default
- Day and Name
- Month and Name
- Numeric
- Post Name (used by most of WordPress Themes on web now-a-days)
- Custom Structure

I didn't quite understand your question, Did you change the **Permalink** some how? Are you getting redirected? Or, Would like to get redirected? Because if you would, I'm afraid it's not possible for you to do **URL's** redirecting this way (Unless if you want to mess around with your code, then go ahead).

Something nice about **Permalinks** in *WordPress* is that it offers to us an awesome flexibility to create our own custom **URI**. It gives to us some sort of *tags* to mess around that looks something like this:

- %year%
- %monthnum%
- %day%
- %hour%
- %post_id%
- etc...

Go to https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks to know more about the **Custom URI Tags** and see how **WordPress URI Formats** is structured.

If you're planning to add some extra information to your **URI** that the *WordPress* does not offer (let's say a `-` symbol), you need to know that, we don't place this kind of stuff explicitly on the **URL**, if you do so, it'll break your *Theme* or *Plugin*, and it might give you a hard time to figure it out.

For security measures **URL's** are encoded by the Browser, blocking any kind of suspicious/malicious attempt to hack your *Theme* or *Plugin*. Please take a look to [HTML URL Encoding by W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp), it will give you a set of `UTF-8` encoding standards.

### Real World Example

Let's say that you want to create the following structure:

> www.test.com/123-my-post-title-name

I suppose it could be easily done by selecting the **Custom Structure** from *WordPress Formats* and place at the **URI** input this `%post_id%%2D%%postname%` instruction.

Comment: Yeah. I know how to make Permalinks. 

I made this: www.test.com/123-my-post-title-name
And I also want to make redirection from www.test.com/123 to www.test.com/123-my-post-title-name

Now in Wordpress redirection works like this www.test.com/?p=123

Comment: Why would you do this? Because when the user open your **Single Post Page** the **URL** will be already `www.teste.com/123-my-post-title-name`, and there's no need for redirection.

Comment: Yes, but I want the link to be short when I give it to somebody. 

www.test.com/123 which redirects to www.teste.com/123-123-my-post-title-name looks better.

Comment: In my opinion there is no need to create a **Custom Short URL** for (as I suppose) a small *theme*, there are plenty of **URL Shortener Services** out there on web, such as [Google URL Shortener](https://goo.gl/), [Bitly](https://bitly.com/) and many others. There is an option if you really want to create a **Custom Short URL**, please would you [click here](http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-create-your-own-customized-short-url-for-your-blog/) to see more of how you can do it? Thanks :D

Comment: Its bad variant